# Only show results from particular list if I am inside that list

Tags: 2013, 2010, search, search-scope

In SP 2010 if I do search on home page of site then will show me results from all lists.
If I am inside a particular list and then search something then it shows me results from that particular list only.

But in SP 2013 the behaviour is different and even if I am inside a list, when I search something it brings result from whole site.

I can see that in SP 2010 it is sending query string parameter `u=http://myserver/mywebsite/mylist` while in SP 2013 it always sends `u=http://myserver/mywebsite`

How do I enable same behaviour in SP 2013?

I am using default search box that is normally shown on top right corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How do I enable same behaviour in SP 2013?**

Unfortunately , you can't do the same behavior in SharePoint 2013 at the default search box that is shown on top right corner,

This due to SharePoint 2013 introduces the `Enhanced List toolbar` feature, so the Search behavior has been divided into two section

- [`Search this site`] this the search box that is shown on top right corner
- [`Find an Item`] this the search box at the Enhanced List toolbar.

[image]

So if you need to search only for the current list , you should use `Find an Item` search box.

Comment: Very strange that I don't see this search box in any of the library although I see it in lists.

Comment: I get it that it is not visible because I am using "Server Render" option in library.

Comment: You can get it . by editing your web part > Miscellaneous > Check display Search Box, and you are right if you enable server render , the enhanced toolbar will be removed